# Filtering a Boolean field

Tags: python, django

Trying to filter boolean field, but it brings the error :too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Here is the code

```
def index(request):
    if not request.session.has_key('currency'):
        request.session['currency'] = settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY

    setting = Setting.objects.get(pk=1)
    category = Category.objects.all()
    products_latest = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:4]  # last 4 products
    products_slider = Product.objects.all().order_by('id')[:4]  # first 4 products
    products_picked = Product.objects.all().order_by('?')[:4]  # Random selected 4 products
    products_promoted = Product.objects.filter('promote=True')[:7]  # The error origin

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    promote = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    minamount = models.IntegerField(default=3)
```

Why is it bringing the error and how do i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes around `promote=True`

```
products_promoted = Product.objects.filter(promote=True)[:7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `''`, do:

```
products_promoted = Product.objects.filter(promote=True)[:7]
```

Not:

```
products_promoted = Product.objects.filter('promote=True')[:7]
```